# Why these scripts don't modify all of the list?

Tags: python, for-loop, range

I am practicing lists in python. I am trying to change vowel letters in `['a', 'n', 'a', 'c', 'o', 'n', 'd', 'a']` to `str` `'v'`. I used `for` loop and also `range`, but anything doesn't occur!
What's wrong in my scripts?

Script one:

```
a = list('anaconda')
vowels = list('aeiou')
for i in a:
    if i in vowels:
        i = 'v'
print(a)
```

and also tried:

```
a = list('anaconda')
vowels = list('aeiou')
for i in range(len(a)):
    if i in vowels:
        i = 'v'
print(a)
```

But both of them returns `a` without change: `['a', 'n', 'a', 'c', 'o', 'n', 'd', 'a']`!

Comment: You're just assigning to the local variable `i`; that's not modifying the list in any way.

Comment: Are you looking for a solution that does modify the list, or an explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = list('anaconda')
vowels = list('aeiou')
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] in vowels:
        a[i] = 'v'
print(a)
```

you are using index as value ,you need to use `a[x] for checking whether character is vowel( present in the given list) or not

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let's change it.

Firstly, understand that "i" in that code

```
for i in a
```

is only variable named "i" that equals value from "a" list.
When you write

```
i = 'v'
```

you just change variable "i" but not value from "a" list.

Then you need to change not "i" but value from "a".

Write that:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
   if a[i] in vowels:
      a[i] = 'v'
```

Solution is using "a[i]" to refer to a value in a list.